# Domains in local network for websites

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, ip, local-area-network, website

I have installed **XAMMP** on my local win. server, how can i setup for every website a local domain like. "web1.lan, web2.lan, web3.local"? I already use static IP Adresses in my network...

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is called [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System).